# Error in Laravel 5.1. method save

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Error while trying to save logs in Laravel 5.1. The code and screenshot of the error shown below.
I do not know how to solve them if I appeal to you, I look forward to your help.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Grup;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ControllerGrupos extends Controller
{
    public function agregar_Grupo(Requests $request)
    {
        $nom = $request->get('name');

        $des   = $request->get('descrition');
        $grup = new Grup();


        $grup->nombre      = $nom;
        $grup->descripcion = $des;
        $grup->save();

        return view('grupos.agregar_grupo');
    }

}
```

#### Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the class `Requests` exist?

Comment: yes the class Requests exist

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    //
}

Comment: That's the class 'Request' not 'Requests'

Comment: Don't import "Requests", but Request